# Fastai on google colab

Tags: path, pip, pytorch

Two days back I ran my model using fastai 0.7.0 on google colab.
And for two days I got busy and now if I am trying to run it , its throwing me an error, on the execution of the line
*"from fastai.transforms import ’ .
the error is AttributeError: module ‘torch’ has no attribute ‘float32’.[image: Image showing the error]

Answer (score 4):

The following should get you up and running with the 0.7.0 version of fast.ai (used by v2 of the course) on Google Colab:

```
!pip install -q "fastai==0.7.0" Pillow==4.1.1 torchtext==0.2.3
!apt-get -qq install -y libsm6 libxext6 && pip install -q -U opencv-python

from wheel.pep425tags import get_abbr_impl, get_impl_ver, get_abi_tag
platform = '{}{}-{}'.format(get_abbr_impl(), get_impl_ver(), get_abi_tag())
# !apt update -q
!apt install -y libsm6 libxext6

from os import path
accelerator = 'cu80' if path.exists('/opt/bin/nvidia-smi') else 'cpu'
torch_whl = f"http://download.pytorch.org/whl/{accelerator}/torch-0.3.0.post4-{platform}-linux_x86_64.whl"
!pip install -q {torch_whl} torchvision image
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm surprised that this was the only working answer after a lot of searching.

Any idea about how to satisfy: `mizani 0.5.3 has requirement pandas>=0.23.4, but you'll have pandas 0.22.0 which is incompatible.`
`plotnine 0.5.1 has requirement matplotlib>=3.0.0, but you'll have matplotlib 2.1.2 which is incompatible.`
`plotnine 0.5.1 has requirement pandas>=0.23.4, but you'll have pandas 0.22.0 which is incompatible.`

Comment: I am able to use pandas with it, even with this warning

Answer (score 0):

At-last found what was wrong, there was a compatibility issue. 
The pytorch version was 0.3.1 but **torchtext** version was not compatible with it, has to be “torchtext==0.2.3.”

Comment: @KAMLESH KARKI how do you set that to what you said?

Comment: just install the specific version of torch text, like i said.

Answer (score 0):

add below code. i dont really know which dependency call this. but it worked

```
!pip install -q pandas==0.23.4 
!pip install -q joblib==0.12.5 
!pip install -q plotly==3.0.0
```